# can HTML content follow up fancybox easing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, jquery-easing

I have tried to make animation to the popup window that appears with fancybox, the only problem is that I would like that the **html content** must follow up **the animation** as if all html are one **block**,
I tried here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRsjK/11358/),

```
openMethod : "zoomIn",
openEffect : 'elastic',
openEasing: 'easeOutBack', 
openSpeed : 600,
```

but only the wrapper window and border are zooming, I want that text will be bigger and follow the zooming opening animation,
Is that possible?

Comment: do you want text to be bigger or animate alongside with the borders, like zoom in and out?

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz yes I want when the zoomIn effect trigger it will zoom also the text with the borders, (only with zoomIn effect ) Note I am using easeOutBack easing effect : https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html